Electron Browser - temp download files?
I'm writing some cypress tests that download a zip file and unzip it. Cypress uses the Electron browser by default, and I've seen a few failures where the unzip utility says the zip file has "No END header" (but everything looks fine when I look at the file after the test).
My suspicion is that Electron browser saves the downloading file under it's final name while it's downloading, but the download may not be complete when that filename first appears.
Chrome has a feature that saves the 'still in process' downloading file as .crdownload, and only renames it to the final name when the download has completed.
I've looked for documentation on Electron to try and find out how it should behave, but not had any luck.  Can anyone tell me if Electron does/should be doing this 'temporary file name' thing on downloading files?

try to use session's will-download event to intercept these progress and implement similar function in your own electron APP.
const downloadFolder = path.join(app.getPath('downloads'));

  session.defaultSession.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
    const fileName = item.getFilename();
    const tempFilePath = path.join(downloadFolder, `${fileName}.download`);
    const completeFilePath = path.join(downloadFolder, fileName);

    // Set the save path (including a temporary extension)
    item.setSavePath(tempFilePath);

    item.on('updated', (event, state) => {
      if (state === 'interrupted') {
        console.log('Download was interrupted');
      } else if (state === 'progressing') {
        if (item.isPaused()) {
          console.log('Download is paused');
        } else {
          console.log(`Received bytes: ${item.getReceivedBytes()}`);
        }
      }
    });

    item.on('done', (event, state) => {
      if (state === 'completed') {
        console.log('Download successfully completed');
        fs.rename(tempFilePath, completeFilePath, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`File renamed to ${completeFilePath}`);
        });
      } else {
        console.log(`Download failed: ${state}`);
        fs.unlink(tempFilePath, (err) => {
          if (err) console.error(`Failed to delete temporary file: ${err.message}`);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});

